# Поворот спрайта в том-же направлении, что и 3D объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть свойства

```
Image img;
GameObject Target;
```

В которое загружается спрайт и объект который вращается.
Далее делаю следующее:

```
RectTransform rt = img.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
Quaternion r = Quaternion.identity;
r.z = Target.rotation.y;
rt.localRotation = r;
```

Поворачивается только в лева и то не до конца, как-то, на половину.
Кто-то сталкивался уже с такой болью?
Нужно, чтобы спрайт крутился тоже в том же направлении, что и сам объект...
Есть выход?

Подсказка @Yaroslav сработала:

```
Vector3 v = rt.transform.eulerAngles;
v.z = Target.transform.eulerAngles.y;
rt.eulerAngles = v;
```

Но есть проблема...
Он поворачивается в противоположную сторону, то есть объект крутим в право, а спрайт влево и на оборот, как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.transform.eulerAngles = Target.transform.eulerAngles;` ?

---

```
rt.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rt.transform.eulerAngles.x, rt.transform.eulerAngles.y, -Target.transform.eulerAngles.y);
```